# Inserting data from ListA object to 'new Item' form of ListB

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list-form, query-string

I have 2 lists, `candidateList` and `emailList`.

In ListA, and object has various fields such as `candidate` (lookup field) and a `textBody`.
When viewing a `ListA` object I have added a button to `email`.

When selecting `email`, I want to direct the user to the `emailList` newItem form, with the `candidate` and the text from the `bodyText` and populate fields on the newItem form.

I believe that the best way to do this is via a query string, that when I click the `email` button, I pass the data to the newItem form.

Unfortunately I am not sure how to generate the query string to pass, and how to read that query string on the other form to populate.

From what I understand, on my email button press I need to pass the values in the url, like '/Lists/SentMails/NewFormInsert.aspx?candidate=@Candidate=1&bodyText=@BodyText'
But those values are within a `<xsl:value-of select="@Candidate"/>`, so I need to somehow get the xsl value first as a string before I can pass it via the url?

Stumped at this point. :(

Any ideas or suggestions?
Thanks!

(Using SharePoint Designer 2013)

Answer (score 0):

Your use case can be divided into 2 parts.

**1.** Generate a URL which contains query strings:

As you have already placed a button on view form, then first get the url of email list new form which would be something like this `http://yoursite/Lists/YourListName/NewForm.aspx?Source=value`

you can tune it to `http://yoursite/Lists/YourListName/NewForm.aspx?yourQuery=value&yourSecondQuery=value`

Now if your button is html `<button>` then it will not have href and you will need redirect action via onclick event. So it is good to have a `<a>` tag. Which will allow you to place above URL in href.

**2.** On the destination form, retrieve values of query strings

Now on the email New Item form, you can have below JavaScript function.

```
var firstValue = '',
    secondValue = '';
function getQueryString () {
    try {
        var q = (function (a) {
            if (a == "") return {};
            var b = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
                var p = a[i].split('=');
                if (p.length != 2) continue;
                b[p[0]] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
            }
            return b;
        })(window.location.search.substr(1).split('&'));

        //Here q is an array which will contain your query strings. So just use name and value can be fetched
        if (!isEmpty(q["queryStringName"])) {
            firstValue = q["queryStringName"];
        }
        if (!isEmpty(q["secondQueryStringName"])) {
            secondValue = q["secondQueryStringName"];
        }

    }
    catch (err) {
        alert("Error");
    }
}

function isEmpty (value) {
    return (value == null || value.length === 0);
}
```